# No GUI in antiX 19.0

Tags: debian, x11, antix

I'm trying to install antiX in a pretty old system. Compaq Presario 5000 to be precise. It is almost 20 years old and having 256 MB RAM and Pentium 3 processor on board. It's having Windows XP running currently. During the boot from the installation medium, I'm not getting GUI installer but CLI. I still completed the installation. Upon reboot after installation it still shows only command line interface. During boot up there is a failed step which is related to X11. Full Xorg.0.log is available [here](http://paste.debian.net/1174813). Is it really possible to install antiX on this system? I was curious when I found antiX can run on 256 MB machines as well. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your log files say that there is no available framebuffer device. Does `/dev/fb0` exist?

Comment: I've noticed the same but I don't know what it is. Is it graphics card?

Comment: The framebuffer device is a special filesystem node, allowing you to manipulate individual pixels on the screen (instead of outputting ASCII text to a raw terminal). X depends on this working because this is one of the ways to manipulate pixels on a Linux machine. A friend of mine wrote a great blog post on this, which I can eventually dig up. If `/dev/fb0` does not exist, chances are X won't be able to run, simply because it can't manipulate your screen. As a side note, framebuffer errors generally have nothing to do with drivers or cards - you should be fine on that extent. Does fb0 exist?

Comment: Thank you. /dev/fb0 does not exist. What could I possibly do next?

Comment: Interesting. Does `/dev` exist? Could you by any chance send over an image of what it contains?